# How to compress and encode png and plist files in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, compression, png, plist, encode

In the "Packaging" section of Xcode build settings, there are the following options:

Compress PNG Files (YES)
Property List Output Encoding (Binary)

By default, it should compress & encode the files, but in finder when I open package contents of the app (located in the build directory of the derived data folder of Xcode), I can still see the png / plist files looking the same!

The png files are not compressed, and the plists are not encoded. Why ? Is this always the case when running on the simulator? (its an iOS app I'm working on). Is there some setting I must change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the files are compressed only on the device, and not on the simulator.